# Display console.log equivalent of PHP onto leetcode console terminal

Tags: php, console, console.log

How can I console.log/error_log when coding on the leetcode terminal in PHP such that I can see my messages on the console terminal?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard PHP constructs such as: `echo` and functions such as: `print_r()`, `var_dump()`.

Example:

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfIHm.png)

[Console result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaRFj.png)

Comment: Tried using echo but nothing gets printed

Comment: Can you provide the code you're trying?

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$txt = "PHP";
echo "I love $txt!";
echo "<script> console.log('".$txt ."')</script>";
// or you can use alert
// echo "<script> alert('".$txt ."')</script>";
?>
```

Comment: I tried using echo but it didnt work

Comment: send link of that page

Comment: Adding closing `?>` is actually a bad practice as a terminating statement. You should ignore it.

Comment: then what should I use?